# Join/lookup agregation on mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, schema

I'm currently making an achievement system and trying to save it in two collections.
One collection that contains the name and id,
and the other collections with users and their progress.

I've been looking at Aggregation, and on $lookup, and made some progress, but I'm not sure what would be necessary to do to make the desired output that I would like.

If the user exists in achievements, get the progress value and their userid with the collection, if not, make progress value to 0.

Wouldnt this be some kind of joining in for example Mysql?, how would this be in MongoDB?

variable `userid = 33;`

attempt:

```
db.getCollection('achievements').aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "achievement_users",
         localField: "id",
         foreignField: "id",
         as: "inventory_docs"
       }
  }
])
```

achievement schema:

```
{
    "name" : "testing",
    "id" : 1,
    "max" : 12,
},

{
    "name" : "testing2",
    "id" : 2,
    "max" : 12,

}
```

achievement user:

```
{
    "userid" : 33,
    "id" : 1,
    progress: 1,
},
 {
        "userid" : 446,
        "id" : 1,
        progress: 1,
    }
```

Desired output:

```
{
name: "testing",
id: 1,
userid: 33,
progress: 1,
    max : 12,

},
{
name: "testing2",
id: 2,
progress: 0,
    max : 12,

},
```

EDIT:

I need all achievements that the user have done, and not have done ( not have done = progress = 0).

it may be achievements that the user havent done. i want them listed too, but to have the progress value of 0.

update 2:
Also need it to give me results while there are no match in achievement_users for that spesific userid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.achievement_users.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "userid": 33 }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "achievement",
    "let": { "id": "$id", "progress": "$progress", "userid": "$userid" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$addFields": {
        "progress": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$id", "$$id"] }, "$$progress", 0] },
        "userid": "$$userid"
      }}
    ],
    "as": "inventory_docs"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$inventory_docs" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$inventory_docs" }}
])
```

Comment: But the useid is only stored in users achievement list, not the achievement itself. I could do the other way around but then I won’t get the achievements the user don’t have :/

Comment: I have started the aggregation from `user_acheivement` collection. Have a look at the answer

Comment: thanks @Anthony, is there a way to shorten the time? ( on 5k users row and 50 achievements it took 1.5sec).

Comment: also @anthony, i need the achievements ( with progress value of 0) if the user dont have it. So i need everything it have completed, and not have completed( any rows).

Comment: create an index on `userid` field to reduce the time. **i need the achievements ( with progress value of 0) if the user dont have it. So i need everything it have completed, and not have completed( any rows).** I didn't get this

Comment: updated main thread, does that makes it clearer for you? basically need to get rows the user dont have too.

Comment: Updated my answer. Have a check

Comment: thanks, really close now! not getting the accurate progress values btw: http://prntscr.com/n1d9jp ( should be 44 in my db).  and for those rows who dont exist the value is 0.0 atm.

Comment: Here you can check the output. https://mongoplayground.net/p/mKgKNZNdVFA. Please let me know the issue.

Comment: Still is there issue with the above answer?

Comment: at the link i mentioned i have a progress of 44, but its not displayed.

Comment: Sorry but I am not getting you. You should be more specific about you problem.

Comment: if you look at the link i provided, i have a progress value in my achievement_users database ( value 44). but in the results, it wont show the corresponding progress value.

Comment: Updated my answer. Try it again

Comment: now I think you should ask a new question if you have more doubts please.

Comment: Hope My comment on that question helped you

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution if you want to perform something similar to `LEFT JOIN`:

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "user",
        localField: "id",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "inventory_docs"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {path: "$inventory_docs", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        userid: "$inventory_docs.userid",
        progress: {$cond: {if: "$inventory_docs.progress", then: "$inventory_docs.progress", else: 0 }},
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        inventory_docs: 0
    }
}])
```

`$lookup` create an array from the joined collection

`$unwind` split the array in records

`$addFields` extract the field you want as you want

`$cond` replace an empty progress with 0

`$project` for a final clean up

Comment: thanks! could i get every result where only the userid match? instead of everyone? :)

Comment: For use, add a $match at the beginning of the pipeline `{$match: {id: {$in: ['1', '2']}}}`

Comment: so like only get results where userid = 33 from the user row, will only display achievements for that user ( done and not done ofc).

Comment: cause i dont know how the match would be when i only have userid from user collections.

Comment: also @Julien, i could reverse it from users collection so it would be mach, get achievement, but then it wouldnt get the achievements i done have. is there any good idea to solve ? :)